# Magnetic force and Electrostatic force

Tags: electrostatics

We know that two or more static charges exert Electrostatic force on each other.

But due to the Force they will repel or attract each other and thus move (The charges are not fixed).

But we know that moving charges also produce magnetic field or We can say that moving charge exert magnetic force.

So while solving for the net force problems why don't we include them in the answer?

I know something at rest or in motion is relative but still net force won't change right?

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Magnetic force is responsible for the change in direction of the velocity of the moving charges. It does not affect the net force on the charge. You can consider a charge moving into a magnetic field, the charge starts getting distracted, has a parabolic path, is due to the magnetic field. Here also only the direction of motion got changed.